# Xamarin exited with code 2

Tags: .net, xamarin, monodevelop, nancy

I have a Xamarin - Nancy Application, and I've imported all the necessary libraries. But when I make a debug of my app the xamarin's console throws this error.

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.2.6/lib/mono/4.0/Microsoft.Common.targets: Error: Command '
if Debug == Debug (
xcopy /s /y /R "/Users/ivan/Projects/sisam/src/packages/Nancy.Viewengines.Razor.0.21.1/BuildProviders/Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.BuildProviders.dll" "/Users/ivan/Projects/sisam/src/app/Sisam.UI/bin/"
xcopy /s /y /R "/Users/ivan/Projects/sisam/src/packages/Nancy.Viewengines.Razor.0.21.1/lib/Net40/Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.dll" "/Users/ivan/Projects/sisam/src/app/Sisam.UI/bin/"
)
if Debug == Debug (
xcopy /s /y /R "/Users/ivan/Projects/sisam/src/.nuget/../../../packages/Nancy.Viewengines.Razor.0.22.2/BuildProviders/Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.BuildProviders.dll" "/Users/ivan/Projects/sisam/src/app/Sisam.UI/bin/"
xcopy /s /y /R "/Users/ivan/Projects/sisam/src/.nuget/../../../packages/Nancy.Viewengines.Razor.0.22.2/lib/Net40/Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.dll" "/Users/ivan/Projects/sisam/src/app/Sisam.UI/bin/"
)
if Debug == Debug (
xcopy /s /y /R "/Users/ivan/Projects/sisam/src/.nuget/../../packages/Nancy.Viewengines.Razor.0.22.2/BuildProviders/Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.BuildProviders.dll" "/Users/ivan/Projects/sisam/src/app/Sisam.UI/bin/"
xcopy /s /y /R "/Users/ivan/Projects/sisam/src/.nuget/../../packages/Nancy.Viewengines.Razor.0.22.2/lib/Net40/Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.dll" "/Users/ivan/Projects/sisam/src/app/Sisam.UI/bin/"
)' exited with code: 2. (Sisam.UI)
```

Really I don't know what is happening, and i would appreciate whatever idea. Thanks.

Comment: When does it throw this error?

Comment: In the debugging. [link] (http://s22.postimg.org/4ab02t8v5/Sisam_UI_web_config_Xamarin_Studio.png)

Comment: Yes, but is it during build, or after it launches into debugging, or after you press something? I need to know a specific time during the entire debugging period.

Comment: Is only when the debug starts.

Answer (score 0):

[xcopy](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx) does not exist on the Mac which is why the build is failing.

The Nancy.ViewEngine.Razor NuGet package adds a post build step to your project. This post build step is using xcopy to copy dlls to the bin folder. Unfortunately xcopy is not available on the Mac. That will be why the build is failing.

You will need to change the post build step to use a Mac specific command line to copy the files. So you will need to replace the following:

```
xcopy /s /y /R
```

With the [Mac equivalent](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/cp.1.html).